# Android creating multiple fragments or better way?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently building an app that allows users to upload blog posts with images to firebase. I have them being displayed into a recycler view in a fragment. I want to have these post segregated into different categories so that the user can browse to the respected category to view post around that topic. Do i have to create a new fragment for each category (10+) or is there a better way to go about it looking for guidance on how to proceed from here

[image: App screenshots]

[image: App screenshots]

Comment: If the layout does not change and just the cards need to change you can just update the adapter and i believe there are some built in animations to transition between the old cards and the new ones. You should think at fragments as screens that hold some state, witch comes very useful in navigation between the different screens. if you use fragments the you can use a view pager to scroll between them.

Answer (score 0):

If layout dose not changed, just create one fragment for all of your categories. Then call your fragment from your activity like this:

```
MyFragment.newInstance(your data);
```

At newInstance() method of your fragment pass data that you want to show in fragment.
Then at fragment get that data and pass it to your recyclerview adapter.

Comment: Sorry just a little unsure on what your saying so I should create one fragment (class and layout) for a model then in the java write code that displays the given category based on what the user pressed?